# Help pages: Add "website recommendations" to the list of off-topic subjects

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page does not explicitly mention that website recommendations are off-topic. It says that "requests for specific service provider recommendations" are off-topic. Some people may reason that this allows recommendations of websites that display free data.

Context: [Is it possible to comprehensively compare personal tax rates between countries?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139932/is-it-possible-to-comprehensively-compare-personal-tax-rates-between-countries)

> I apologize if this might be the wrong site to ask, I didn't specifically see anything in the help section going against "recommendation questions".
>
> [...]

In a [comment by the OP](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139932/are-there-websites-to-comprehensively-compare-personal-tax-rates-between-countri?noredirect=1#comment279917_139932):

> [dont-ask](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Doesn't mention recommendation once; the [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page mentions it in the context of Investing/Saving (first three mentions), and then again in the specific context of investing (i.e., paid) providers further down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the examples under the "requests for specific service provider recommendations" was already "a website for learning about something". I've just edited that to "a website" just in case anyone thought the previous wording implied that other kinds of websites were ok...